# How to run GUI software in K8S pod?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to run xclock inside the K8S pod after connecting to it via MobarXterm tool, but I've been unsuccessful, so please tell me how to run a GUI software like xclock inside the K8S pod.

I write a matlab-deployment.yaml , the content is :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: matlab
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30005
    port: 2222
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 22
    name: ssh
  selector:
    app: matlab
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: matlab-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: matlab
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: matlab
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: matlab
        image: docker-harvor/train/matlab
        env:
        - name: DISPLAY
          value: ":0.0"
        ports:
        - name: ssh
          containerPort: 22
        volumeMounts:
        - name: x-11
          mountPath: "/tmp/.X11-unix"
        - name: localtime
          mountPath: "/etc/localtime"
      volumes:
      - name: x-11
        hostPath:
          path: "/tmp/.X11-unix"
          type: Directory
      - name: localtime
        hostPath:
          path: "/etc/localtime"
          type: File
```

Then I use command:

`kubectl apply -f  matlab-deployment.yaml`

And I use command into a pod:

`kubectl exec -it matlab-deployment-698fff79dc-d92jc /bin/bash`

When I run xclock inside the pod, there is no graphical display of:

[image]

This image docker-harvor/train/matlab itself  comes with a graphical interface

If I want to run xclock inside a pod with a graphical interface, what do I need to change